# Clebsch-Gordan Series and Rotation Matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

I am referring to the first inequality in equation 3.390 on page 217 of Sakurai's "[Modern Quatum Mechanics](https://emc2physics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/J.-J.-Sakurai_-Jim-Napolitano-Modern-Quantum-Mechanics-2021-Cambridge-University-Press-libgen.li_.pdf)" textbook. The quantity $D^{(j)}(R)$ refers to a rotation operator in the ket space spanned by the angular momentum eigenkets with eigenvalue $j$. I need to know how to get
$$\langle j_{1}j_{2}; m_{1}m_{2}\lvert D(R) \rvert j_{1}j_{2}; m'_{1}m'_{2} \rangle = \langle j_{1} m_{1}\lvert D(R) \rvert j_{1}m'_{1}\rangle \langle j_{2} m_{2}\lvert D(R) \rvert j_{2}m'_{2}\rangle.$$

Here, the kets $\rvert j_{1}j_{2}; m_{1}m_{2} \rangle$ are simultaneous eigenkets of $\textbf{J}^{2}_{1}, \textbf{J}^{2}_{2}, J_{1z}$ and $J_{2z}$.

Comment: what is the link between your question and the Clebsch-Gordan series?  Are you looking for the transformation properties of $D^J$ functions as a sum of products of $D^{j_1}D^{j_2}$?

Answer (score 1):

The rotation operator
\begin{align}
D(R)=e^{i\vec \omega\cdot \vec L}&
=e^{i\vec \omega \cdot(\vec L^{(1)}+\vec L^{(2)})} = e^{i\vec \omega \cdot\vec L^{(1)}}e^{i\vec \omega \cdot\vec L^{(2)}}\, ,\\
&=D(R)_1D(R)_2
\end{align}
acts on the individual states in a product just like any finite transformation (say parity) acts on the individual states in a product.  This follows because the operators acting on $\vert j_1m_1\rangle$ commute with those acting on $\vert j_2m_2\rangle$.

Note that, by expanding the exponential in series for small $\vec \omega$, one recovers the action of infinitesimal generators
$$
\vec\omega\cdot \vec L \vert j_1 m_1\rangle \vert j_2 m2\rangle = 
\left[\vec \omega \cdot \vec L^{(1)} \vert j_1 m_1\rangle \right]\vert j_2 m2\rangle 
+\vert j_1m_1\rangle\left[\vec \omega \cdot \vec L^{(2)} \vert j_2 m_2\rangle \right]\, ,
$$
showing the essential way in which generators of *infinitesimal* transformation differ in their actions from operators of finite transformations.

Comment: What @ZeroTheHero is getting at is that the second line of your two equations is  the *definition* of the the operator $D(R)$ first line. In other words it says that that $D(R)$ in the first line is  the tensor product of the two representations.

Comment: By $D(R)_{1}$ do we mean the representation of the rotation matrix corresponding to angular momentum eigenvalue $j_{1}$?

Comment: You refer to $D(R)$ as a rotation operator so $D(R)_1$ is the same rotation operator acting on system 1 only.